# SCEP: imitate potential threat in both live and regular scanner to inspect logs

Tags: powershell, anti-virus, malware

I am doing some powershell stuff to parse a few logs at work. I would also like to collect some information from the SCEP logs. I find the amount of logs available as well as the different locations in which they are stored a bit overwhelming to say the least.

I would like to extract the logs reporting that a potential virus was found in both the live and the "regular scanner.

A similiar question has already been answered here: 
[Reporting SCEP update and scan](https://serverfault.com/questions/642534/reporting-scep-update-and-scan)

I have `eicar` for testing purposes here. So how would I imitate a potential positive finding in both scanners so that I can figure out to which file the scanners log to?

Thanks in advance

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as the "regular" scanner is concerned in `%systemdrive%\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Support\ MPLog-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXX.log` offers a wealth of information.

Here are some interesting patterns to search for:

```
Threat Name # record(s) of malware detection 
signature updated via # self-explanatory 
scan source # record of scheduled scan/running scan on demand 
Expensive file # expensive i.e. large files found during a scan (this information can be used to enhance scanning performance)
```

Anyway, live detections are apparently not written to the aforementioned file!